# "as appropriate"

Tags: word-usage

I recently read a commercial contract. In which, there is a sentence...

> The seller shall make available to the buyer (or shall present to the bank specified by the buyer) the following documents (tick corresponding boxes and indicate, as appropriate, the number of copies to be provided)

I don't understand why they use "as appropriate" and why the comma is placed after "as appropriate". Please help!

Comment: The commas delineating ***as appropriate*** are there to indicate this is a *syntactically optional* adverbial element. It's modifying ***indicate***, to convey the implication that *not all the listed documents* need to be accompanied by an indication of how many copies are required (presumably, the default is ***one copy*** for any document that doesn't explicitly specify some larger number). Note that not all writers *today* would include those two commas (the general tendency is towards reducing the use of punctuation marks).

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way, I still have a question. In the above sentence, I don't understand the phrase "make available". What does " make available" mean? And is this phrase used a lot by native speakers?

Comment: *The seller shall make available to the buyer these documents* has almost no connection to "normal English" - it's an extreme example of legal gobbledygook, *completely* irrelevant to the needs of people learning English today. I can't be bothered to explain the syntactic constructions, but what it *means* is that the seller is legally obliged to give those documents to the buyer (or if not actually *give* the original documents away, seller must at least allow the buyer to examine those documents thoroughly, to satisfy himself that they are in fact valid).

Comment: so Do you have another phrase to replace "make available" in the above sentence ?

Comment: Absolutely! *The [seller shall **furnish** the buyer with...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=furnish+the+buyer%2Cmake+available+to+the+buyer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is far more common, and for most purposes means *exactly* the same thing. But note that this is "legalese" - it may or may not have been tested and established in court that ***make available*** can include only allowing the other party to ***see, verify, and return*** some documents, whereas ***furnish*** must allow the other party to ***keep*** them. But I'm not a lawyer! :)

Comment: Note that if the *exact* meaning is contractually important to you (because you're either bound by an existing contract, or drawing up a new one of your own) you shouldn't rely on what anyone says here. You *must* consult a properly-trained professional lawyer.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you so so much!

Comment: To **make (something) available** is a  generic phrase that means to provide something in such a way that it of use or of benefit. That which is "available" is accessible and useful.  A wide variety of things can be "made available". For example, a party to a lawsuit can make evidentiary documents available to the other party; or a governmental body can make low-interest-rate loans available to those who have been hit by a natural disaster such as flood, earthquake, tornado, or fire. A charitable organization can make  shelter and food available to homeless people.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma after ‘as appropriate’ because it is a relative clause. ‘as appropriate’ means ‘when it would be reasonable to do so’.